# PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. How to convert in to a more efficient way via pd.concat with designated column name

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, concatenation

I got following warning while running under python 3.8 with the newest pandas.

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.

this is the place where I compile my data into one single dataframe, and also where the problem pops up.

```
def get_all_score():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for name, code in get_code().items():
        global count
        count += 1
        print("ticker：" + name, "trade_code：" + code, "The {} data updated".format(count))
        try:
            df[name] = indicator_score(code)['total']
            time.sleep(0.33334)
        except:
            continue
    return df
```

I tried to look up in the forum, but I can't figure out how to manipulate with two variables, `df[name]`is my column name, and `indicator_score(code)['total']` is my column output data, all the fractured dataframes are added horizontally, shown as bellow:

```
     a     b     c     <<<   zz
1    30    40    10          21
2    41    50    11          33
3    44    66    20          29
4    51    71    19          10
5    31    88    31          60
6    60    95    40          70
.
.
.
```

what would be a neat way to use `pd.concat()` to solve my issue? thanks.

Comment: I figured out a way, but it looks a bit clumsy, It might return Error on me if one little glitch goes south, and waste one good hour of mine.  I am still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround on this issue, but it seems not that reliable, one little glitch can totally ruin the past process. Here are my code:

```
def get_all_score():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    name_list = []
    for name, code in get_code().items():
        global count
        count += 1
        print("ticker：" + name, "trade_code：" + code, "The {} data updated".format(count))
        try:
            name_list.append(name)
            df = pd.concat([df, indicator_score(code)['总分']], axis=1)
            # df[name] = indicator_score(code)['总分']
            # time.sleep(0.33334)
        except:
            name_list.remove(name)
            continue
    df.columns = name_list
    return df
```

I tried to replace `name` for column name before concat process, however I failed to do so. I only figured out how to replace column name after the concat process. This is such a pain. Does anyone have a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

`df[name] = indicator_score(code)['总分'].copy()`
should solve your poor performance issue, I suppose, give it a try mate.